# How to create FunctionCall statement with arguments and add in function

Tags: java, javascript, mozilla, rhino

I need to create FunctionCall statement like **Utiliy.initialize("value")** and add this in first line of every function of js file.

Below is the code using which I am trying to create FunctionCall

```
private FunctionCall getFunctionCall() {
        FunctionCall functionCall = new FunctionCall();
        Name name =  new Name();
        name.setIdentifier("initialize");
        functionCall.setTarget(name);
}
```

below is the code I am using to add in every functionNode

```
class FunctionVisitor implements NodeVisitor {
        @Override
        public boolean visit(AstNode node) {
             if (node.getClass() == FunctionNode.class) {
                FunctionNode fun = (FunctionNode) node;
                fun.addChildrenToFront(getFunctionCall());
            }
            return true;
        }

    }
```

Please suggest how I can create FunctionCall with arguments and how I can print created FunctionCall statement to test.
Is there any tool available to view javascript nodes like java ASTVIEW viewer?

Comment: Is this java or javascript?  The question probably should not have both tags.

Comment: @jfriend00: in this particular case that's fine, because Rhino is a Javascript engine written in Java.

Comment: @georg - but the code is either Java or Javascript (appears to be Java) and that's the tag that should be on it because that's whose help the OP wants to attract.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create StringLiteral as a argument and add it to functionCall, in othere case it could be NumberLiteral, ArrrayLiteral etc. (see: http://javadox.com/org.mozilla/rhino/1.7R4/org/mozilla/javascript/ast/AstNode.html)

```
private FunctionCall getFunctionCall() {
        FunctionCall functionCall = new FunctionCall();
        Name name =  new Name();
        name.setIdentifier("initialize");
        functionCall.setTarget(name);
        StringLiteral arg = new StringLiteral();
        arg.setValue("value");
        arg.setQuoteCharacter('"');
        functionCall.addArgument(arg);
        return functionCall;
}

class FunctionVisitor implements NodeVisitor {
        @Override
        public boolean visit(AstNode node) {
             if (node.getClass() == FunctionNode.class) {
                FunctionNode fun = (FunctionNode) node;
                if(fun.getName().equals("initialize")) //prevents infinit loop
                {
                     return true;
                }
                fun.getBody().addChildrenToFront(new EmptyStatement()); // adds ';', I don't know if required
                fun.getBody().addChildrenToFront(getFunctionCall());//no fun.addChildrenToFront
            }
            return true;
        }

    }
```

You can print every corect AstNode by toSource() method. I hope this will help.

Comment: @@Dominik Kunicki:  thnakx alot it is working fine except EmptyStatement line mozilla does not have EmptyStatement import and giving error. can u please tell how i can add ";"

Comment: I have class: org.mozilla.javascript.ast.EmptyStatement; in Rhino 1.7R4, can you import it? Maybe in your implementation this is the different class. What I can recomend is to set breakpoint in FunctionVisitor and check what class is representing ';' node in your implementation. Let me know if you find something.

Comment: @@Dominik Kunicki: great!!! EmptyStatement is also working and adding ";". thankx a lot.

Comment: @@Dominik Kunicki: Can you please tell how  to save file after changes.   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27525677/how-to-save-js-file-after-adding-child-node